# Split categorical values of one column into more columns

Tags: r, variables, split, survey

I am dealing with the situation where data from a survey question have multiple answers. So a respondent who has answered the question was able to tick more than one box. The result is that data set includes the multiple answers together in as one value.

```
df <- c("VrolijkGemotiveerd", "RelaxtGemotiveerdVrolijk", "Neutraal", "TrotsGezegend", "Neutraal", "Neutraal", "VermoeidGemotiveerd")
```

I want to split for example `RelaxtGemotiveerdVrolijk` into `Column 1`: `Relaxt` en `Column 2`: `Gemotiveerd` and `Column 3`: `Vrolijk`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to split each string wherever an upper-case letter occurs, which can be done using a regular expression. There are lots of functions that you can use to apply regexes in this way, e.g. `strsplit()`, `stringr::str_split()` etc, but `tidyr` has a function specifically for adding new columns using this method:

```r
df <- data.frame(
    c1 = c("VrolijkGemotiveerd", "RelaxtGemotiveerdVrolijk", "Neutraal", 
           "TrotsGezegend", "Neutraal", "Neutraal", "VermoeidGemotiveerd")
)

tidyr::separate(df, c1, into = c("c2", "c3", "c4"), 
                sep = "(?<=.)(?=[[:upper:]])", fill = "right", remove = FALSE)
#>                         c1       c2          c3      c4
#> 1       VrolijkGemotiveerd  Vrolijk Gemotiveerd    <NA>
#> 2 RelaxtGemotiveerdVrolijk   Relaxt Gemotiveerd Vrolijk
#> 3                 Neutraal Neutraal        <NA>    <NA>
#> 4            TrotsGezegend    Trots    Gezegend    <NA>
#> 5                 Neutraal Neutraal        <NA>    <NA>
#> 6                 Neutraal Neutraal        <NA>    <NA>
#> 7      VermoeidGemotiveerd Vermoeid Gemotiveerd    <NA>
```

**EDIT**: Updated to use the regular expression from @Laterow's answer, as mine was a bit broken.

Comment: Nice answer. Just wanted to point out that sometimes the last letter of the words are being dropped.

Comment: Just spotted that! Updated to use @Laterow's regex.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

Assuming that categories always start with capital letters, use `strsplit` with `perl`-compatible regular expressions:

```
strsplit(df, "(?<=.)(?=[[:upper:]])", perl = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Vrolijk"     "Gemotiveerd"

[[2]]
[1] "Relaxt"      "Gemotiveerd" "Vrolijk"    

[[3]]
[1] "Neutraal"

[[4]]
[1] "Trots"    "Gezegend"

[[5]]
[1] "Neutraal"

[[6]]
[1] "Neutraal"

[[7]]
[1] "Vermoeid"    "Gemotiveerd"
```

**Rationale**

`strsplit` let's you split strings by a pattern. Regular expressions allow you to operate on patterns in strings. The pattern is to find the capital letter (i.e. `[[:upper:]]`). The other parts are necessary to properly split at each capital letter, to maintain the letter you split on, and to split before the capital letter rather than after.

This code returns a list that you can then use for further processing.